# Retrieve images from Instagram that contains more tag

Tags: image, tags, instagram, hashtag

I'm retrieving images from Instagram but I can't figure out why with this call:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/trytag/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I can only retrieve images with one single trytag.
So if I post an image with more tags the link above can't retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The current [Instagram v1.0 API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) doesn't currently allow for multiple tag search. You could query for each tag separately and combine your results, or an alternative is to use a third party search like [Mixagram](http://mixagram.com), which is most likely doing the same thing but doesn't require an enormous amount of storage space upfront.